# Composite Function Type problem

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Let $f\left( x \right) = {x^2}$ and $g\left( x \right) = \sin x$ for all $x \in R$. Then the set of all x satisfying $\left( {fogogof} \right)\left( x \right) = \left( {gogof} \right)\left( x \right)$, where $\left( {fog} \right)\left( x \right) = f\left( {g\left( x \right)} \right)$ is

(A) $ \pm \sqrt {n\pi } ,n \in \left\{ {0,1,2,...} \right\}$

(B) $ \pm \sqrt {n\pi } ,n \in \left\{ {1,2,...} \right\}$

(C) $\frac{\pi }{2} + 2n\pi ,n \in \left\{ {..., - 2, - 1,0,1,2,...} \right\}$

(D) $ 2n\pi ,n \in \left\{ {..., - 2, - 1,0,1,2,...} \right\}$

I am not able to solve this problem because it is composite function

Comment: $fogogof=(\sin(\sin(x^2)))^2$ and $gogof=\sin(\sin(x^2))$, and it looks like $(A)$ is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is $f(M)=M$ where $M=g\circ g\circ f(x)$. The fixed points of $f$ are $0,1$. Hence we want $g\circ g\circ f(x)=\sin(\sin x^2)=0,1$.

For $0$, you have $\sin x^2=n\pi$ which lies in $[-1,1]$ only for $n=0$. Thus $\sin x^2=0\implies x^2=k\pi,k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$.

For $1$, you have $\sin x^2=2m\pi+\pi/2\not\in[-1,1]\forall m\in\Bbb Z$.